# Are dcterms:references and dc:relation are mutually exclusive

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, ontology, linked-data, dublin-core

I'm trying to create a schema for an XML document interchange I'm creating, and there are three variations of reference want to indicate

1. Citation (one article cites another)
2. Derivation (research furthering previous experiments)
3. Dependency (reports that depend on data-sets)

To me, these clearly fall into three dcterms elements:

- Number 1 is `dcterms:references`
- Number 2 should be `dc:source`
- Number 3 should be `dc:relation`

The problem is that [according to my Oxygen (v16.0) editor] both the `dc:relation` and `dcterms:relation` elements conflict with `dcterms:references` as they violate "Unique Particle Attribution" rule.

Looking at the dc & dcterms schema - I can't see why this should be (and all the other substitutionGroup="relation" elements from http://www.dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/dcterms.xsd validate fine.

Is this Oxygen getting it wrong, or is there a definition I'm missing?

Comment: I just stumbled across this question today.  The lack of tags (there's just one, and there are only 7 followers, and only 26 questions) mean that this probably hasn't gotten a lot of attention.  Providing some more tags (something Oxygen related, perhaps, or maybe something related to XSD validation) would probably help.